# Update BindingLIst that is binded to ComboBox, from thread other than the UI thread

Tags: c#, wpf, thread-safety, bindinglist

I'm trying to bind some `BindingList` to `ComboBox` control in my WPF App. But, My `BindingList` is updated from other thread than the UI thread.

I made up a model. All you need is new empty project, with references to WindowsBase, PresentationCore, PresentationFramework, System.Xaml (or simply drop it into predefined WPF window).

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;

public class MainWindow : Window
{
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main()
    {
        new MainWindow().ShowDialog();
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        BindingList<string> list = new BindingList<string>();
        ComboBox cb = new ComboBox();
        cb.SetBinding(ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding() { Source = list });
        this.Content = cb;
        list.Add("Goop");
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            list.Add("Zoop");
        }).Start();
    }
}
```

In the `Goop` line, everything is OK. But, when it reach to the `Zoop` line, it thorws an exception:

> This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its
>   SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread.

In the real project, I can't move the `list.Add` to the UI thread, and I want to keep the Binding issue. How can it be solved? I can transit to other "List" than `BindingList`. I've tried simple `List<string>` but it's worse: it doesn't update at all when I add new items.

**EDIT**

In the reality, the adding-thread knows the list, but it doesn't know the WPF window. The list is in class with internal work, and the GUI inspects the class and view it. So, the `Add` shouldn't know about the GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ,

```
  new Thread(() =>
  {
      if (cb.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
        {
           list.Add("Zoop");
        }
      else
       {
        cb.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                new Action(delegate 
                         {
                           list.Add("Zoop");
                         }
       ));
       }
  }).Start();
```

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. I updated the question. In the reality, the adding-thread knows the list, but it doesn't know the WPF window. The list is in class with internal work, and the GUI inspects the class and view it. So, the `Add` shouldn't know about the GUI.

Comment: You should use a design pattern like MVVM http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/. It's easy to understand and keep away from you problem like that.

Answer (score 0):

The UI thread is lock. 
Then you have to give it your data in a special function.
[MSDN BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.begininvoke.aspx)

by using :

```
BeginInvok(()=>{ // Your stuff});
```

You will ask the UI to update your view as soon as it's possible for it.

Comment: Thanks. I updated the question. In the reality, the adding-thread knows the list, but it doesn't know the WPF window. The list is in class with internal work, and the GUI inspects the class and view it. So, the `Add` shouldn't know about the GUI.